# Add one row from one Data set to Another Data set in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-dataset

There are two DataFrame sets, the one is “Training set”, another is “Test set”. What I want to do is iterate some algorithm(Lets call AAA, which needs RDD input format) by using “Training set plus just one row of Test set”, following below step.

1. Merge entire Training set + “first” row of Test set.
2. Running some algorithm by using 1’s data and get some result.
3. Merge entire Training set + “second” row of Test set.
4. Running some algorithm by using 2’s data and get some result.
5. Merge entire Training set + “third” row of Test set.
   …iterate until last row of Test set.

Actually, in spark manual, I have checked that RDD and DataFrame in spark is immutable, so it was impossible to use

```
Testset.map( x => AAA(Trainset.union(x)) )
```

Also, I have tried to use

```
Testset.map( x => AAA(Trainset.union(Array(x.get(0).toString.toDouble, x.get(1).toString.toDouble, ... x.get(19).toString.toDouble))
```

but, it was not working :(. Is there any solution to make possible above step? If you have a good idea for this problem, please help me.

// Modify and Add condition

Because of time consuming problem, I need to use parallel computing. Therefore, I could not use 'for loop'. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the operation you want is `fold` rather than `map`. However, the fact that both `Testset` and `Trainset` are DataFrames means that won't work, afaik, as you'll run into serialization problems.

Comment: you can convert both dataframes to rdd and use for loop in test data and do the calculation. simple. but remember that your logic is not suitable for distributed/parallel computing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how good an idea this is, but how about:

1) Create a new column on training dataframe called helper with a value of -1

2) Create a new column on test dataframe called helper as follows:

`test.withColumn("helper", monotonically_increasing_id())`

3) Write the output of 2) to disk to ensure the ids never change

4) Union 1) with 3) read back in, and then cache/persist/write to disk and read back in

5) Write a loop that filter the unioned dataframe and does the logic:

```
val data = unioned.filter($"helper" === lit(-1) || $"helper" === lit(n))
val result = logic(data)
```

where n is the value you are looping over, starting at 0 for the first row of test